# Some theme elements displayed incorrectly after upgrade to 16.10

Tags: unity, firefox, themes, 16.10

After upgrading to 16.10 some UI elements are not displaying correctly. Especially dropdown text-fields in windows, eg backup process in duplicity or downloading process in software updater.

[image]

Also in Firefox some dropdown list in search forms are displaying in different parts of the screen.

[image]

Comment: Hello. How UI elements displayed with default theme?

Comment: Hi. With other themes same thing.

Comment: After upgrade to 18.04 problem has disappeared.